# i am trying to create threads in c it throws Segmentation fault (core dumped) how to fix this?

Tags: c

when i try to compile this on ubuntu 20.04 lts it throws a segmentation error ,anyone could tell me how to fix this please?

````
#include<stdio.h>
void* stars (void * arg0)
{ for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
printf("*");
return NULL;
}
void* sharp(void* arg0)
{for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
printf("#");
return NULL;
}
int main(){
pthread_t thread0,thread1;
pthread_join(thread0,NULL);
pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
pthread_create(&thread0,NULL,stars,NULL);
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,sharp,NULL);


}```
````

Comment: threads must be created prior to join.

Comment: Posted the answer for future users :)

Comment: For any function F and any type T, the behavior of `T t; F(t, ...` is undefined.  Since `t` is uninitialized, you can't pass it to a function because the mere act of attempting to read the value is undefined.  So regardless of the semantics of `pthread_join`, invoking `pthread_join(thread0, NULL)` is undefined behavior since `thread0` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign the thread to the respective variables *after* trying to join. Essentially, the `pthread` library is trying to dereference a variable with a garbage value, because you did not assign NULL to them on creation. 
The fix this this:

```
int main(){
    pthread_t thread0,thread1;
    pthread_create(&thread0,NULL,stars,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,sharp,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread0,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
}
```